# Работа с библиотекой RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net, rest

С толкнулся с проблемой что когда выполняешь метод

```
    private async Task<MagentoRestApiResponse<T>> ExecuteAsync<T>(IRestRequest request, bool isSecondTry = false) where T : new()
    {
        var response = await Client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request);
        if (response.ContentType.ToUpperInvariant().Contains("APPLICATION/JSON"))
        {
            return await HandleResponseAsync(response, request, isSecondTry);
        }

        var errors = new List<MagentoError>
        {
            new MagentoError
            {
                Message = "Ответ не содержит json и не может быть десериализован."
            }
        };
        var requestBodyParameter = request.Parameters
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ParameterType.RequestBody);

        var requestContent = requestBodyParameter == null ?
            string.Empty : requestBodyParameter.Value == null ?
            string.Empty : requestBodyParameter.Value.ToString();

        return new MagentoRestApiResponse<T>
        {
            Errors = errors,
            RequestUrl = Client.BuildUri(request),
            ErrorString = response.Content,
            RequestContent = requestContent
        };
    }
```

Получаю json и строго типизированный объект и они разные, в том плане что json полный, а мой объект нет.
Есть `OrderItem` в нем свойство:

```
[JsonProperty("items")]
public IList<NestedItem> NestedItems { get; set; }
```

оно должно быть отличное от `null`, переименовываю свойство на:

```
[JsonProperty("items")]
public IList<NestedItem> Items { get; set; }
```

и все работает. Не понятно в чем проблема!
`NestedItem` это структура.

Comment: RestSharp использует так называемый [SimpleJson](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/simple-json), который имеет свои атрибуты и свою логику обработки JSON.  Например изменение имени происходит через `[DataContract(Name="some name")]` (в документации сказано, что надо добавить еще `#SIMPLE_JSON_DATACONTRACT`). Также RestSharp имеет возможность изменить сериализатор на сторонний, например для запроса это будет `restRequest.JsonSerializer = new RestSharpJsonNetSerializer();`., тогда будет доступно использование `JsonProperty`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо. Можете оформить как ответ.

Comment: Давайте вы сами пишите в него то, что у вас получилось, ибо без проверок и написания тестового приложения я этим заниматься не особо хочу)